# NullPointerException occurs while executing findViewById() in custom ListView adaptor

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I want to create a file manager on Android devices, and I created a custom adaptor as an inner class for the ListView in my file manager.

```
    private static final class FileAdaptor extends BaseAdapter {
           // These variables below would be set in my activity class
            private final List<String> data = new ArrayList<>(); // file name
            private final List<Drawable> data1 = new ArrayList<>(); // file icon
            private final List<String> data2 = new ArrayList<>(); // file modified data
            private final AppCompatActivity activity;
    
            public FileAdaptor(final AppCompatActivity activity) {
                this.activity = activity;
            }
    
            @Override
            public final int getCount() {
                return data.size();
            }
    
            @Override
            public final Object getItem(final int position) {
                return data.get(position);
            }
    
            public final void setData(final List<String> data) {
                if (data != null) {
                    this.data.clear();
                    if (data.size() > 0)
                        this.data.addAll(data);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
    
            public final void setData1(final List<Drawable> data) {
                if (data != null) {
                    this.data1.clear();
                    if (data.size() > 0)
                        this.data1.addAll(data);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
    
            public final void setData2(final List<String> data) {
                if (data != null) {
                    this.data2.clear();
                    if (data.size() > 0)
                        this.data2.addAll(data);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
    
            public final String getData(final int position) {
                return data.get(position);
            }
    
            public final Drawable getData1(final int position) {
                return data1.get(position);
            }
    
            public final String getData2(final int position) {
                return data2.get(position);
            }
    
            @Override
            public final long getItemId(final int position) {
                return 0;
            }
    
            @Override
            public final View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
                View v;
                if (convertView == null) {
                    v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.file_manager_items, parent, false);
                } else v = convertView;
    
                ViewHolder h = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
                if (h == null) {
                    h = new ViewHolder(Objects.requireNonNull(activity.findViewById(R.id.itemIcon)), Objects.requireNonNull(activity.findViewById(R.id.fileName)), Objects.requireNonNull(activity.findViewById(R.id.fileInfo)));
                    v.setTag(h);
                }

/**********************
**Error occurred here**
**********************/

                    h.fileIcon.setImageDrawable(getData1(position));
                    h.fileName.setText(getData(position).substring(getData(position).lastIndexOf("/")));
                    h.fileInfo.setText(getData2(position));
                return v;
            }
    
            private static final class ViewHolder {
                public final AppCompatImageView fileIcon;
                public final AppCompatTextView fileName;
                public final AppCompatTextView fileInfo;
    
                public ViewHolder(@NonNull final AppCompatImageView fileIcon, @NonNull final AppCompatTextView fileName, @NonNull final AppCompatTextView fileInfo) {
                    this.fileIcon = fileIcon;
                    this.fileName = fileName;
                    this.fileInfo = fileInfo;
                }
            }
    
            @NonNull
            @Override
            public final String toString() {
                return "FileAdaptor{" +
                        "data=" + data +
                        ", activity=" + activity +
                        '}';
            }
        }
```

The following below is the layout file for the adaptor in the ListView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/itemIcon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|start"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/fileName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/contents_title"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/fileInfo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/contents" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the layout file for the activity, which includes the listView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/fileManagerContentView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/fileManagerBottomBar">

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/mainContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fileManagerBottomBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/back"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/arrow_back" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/next"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/arrow_next" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/create"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/create" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/refreshContents"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/reload" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageButton
                android:id="@+id/parentFolder"
                style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/up_dir" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/navigation_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

It looks everything works fine for now. However when I tried to call setText for my text view in getView method of my adaptor, the app crashed, with java.lang.NullPointerException output, but I have alredy called findViewById before that.

Later, I have annotated NonNull for the objects in the ViewHold and Objects.requireNonNull for findViewById, but errors still occurred, the error output is the following below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
        at com.example.filemanager.MainActivity$FileAdaptor.getView(MainActivity.java:500)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:3271)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2238)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:838)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:900)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1974)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:3041)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1818)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1584)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
        at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.onLayout(DrawerLayout.java:1231)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:530)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:1059)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:7277)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3679)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3139)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2200)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8960)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:996)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:794)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:729)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:981)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7814)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1068)
```

Can anyone help me to solve this problem

Comment: using try-catch surrounding setText could avoid crashing by NullPointerException, but it does not solve this problem.

Comment: what exactly is written on line 500 in getView method ?

Comment: things written in getView is in the FileAdaptor which I given at the top, FileAdaptor is an inner class of MainActivity

Comment: the error gives a specific line number, i do not know which line number is what. The fact that you give me the entire method does not help me, unless you tell me which line is where

Answer (score 2):

Your code should be like this, because views are part of adapter layout not to the Activity layout.

```
h = new ViewHolder(Objects.requireNonNull(v.findViewById(R.id.itemIcon)), Objects.requireNonNull(v.findViewById(R.id.fileName)), Objects.requireNonNull(v.findViewById(R.id.fileInfo)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
 h = new ViewHolder(Objects.requireNonNull(activity.findViewById(R.id.itemIcon)), Objects.requireNonNull(activity.findViewById(R.id.fileName)), Objects.requireNonNull(activity.findViewById(R.id.fileInfo)));
```

to:

```
h = new ViewHolder(Objects.requireNonNull(v.findViewById(R.id.itemIcon)), Objects.requireNonNull(v.findViewById(R.id.fileName)), Objects.requireNonNull(v.findViewById(R.id.fileInfo)));
```

because you must find child item into your item-view

Answer (score 0):

`findViewById` can return a `Nullable` object, so it doesn't save you from NPE.

You here get NPE because you try to inflate your views with `findViewById` from the activity layout, and they are actually in the item layout which is represented by `convertView`

So, change `activity` with `converView` as in below

```
h = new ViewHolder(Objects.requireNonNull(converView.findViewById(R.id.itemIcon)), Objects.requireNonNull(converView.findViewById(R.id.fileName)), Objects.requireNonNull(converView.findViewById(R.id.fileInfo)));
```